# Verb tense with "already"

Tags: tense, grammaticality

Can you please check the answer of this question?

> A test for the disease …………… already, but the new one will be quicker and cheaper.
>
> a. exists
> b. has existed
> c. is existing
> d. has been existed

I have doubt between choices a and b

Comment: What do you think the answers mean? Why do you think either A or B is the correct answer? What concerns do you have about choosing one over the other?

Comment: because of the adverb "already"

Comment: Only one of these answers is grammatically *wrong*, D, but the choice between the rest is which works *best* and makes the most sense. Do you know about the difference between simple present tense, present perfect, and continuous?

Comment: 'already' could be placed before or after the verb 'exists'. A is the best choice.  It seems that an answer to this question already exists, but @AndrewTobilko chose to put it in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

Option D is incorrect because of the passive voice.

Options A, B, and C are grammatically sound.

Exist is a stative verb. It's not usually used in the present continuous form. *A test is existing already* sounds awkward unless you deliberately try to stress the continuity.

*has existed* would make more sense if you tried bringing attention to the past, e.g. *It has existed since the early 2000s.*

A looks the best to me because the sentence is about the present and the future developments.